# How to handle a form and formset in the same page?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have both a form in and a formset for the same model. The first form that I have is written in HTML because I needed some kind of widgets which Django doesn't have out of the box.

models.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    some_other_field = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        formset = modelformset_factory(MyModel, fields=('name', 'some_other_field', extra=2)
        return render(request, 'index.html', context={'formset': formset})

    def post(self, request):
        formset = modelformset_factory(MyModel, request.POST, fields=('name', 'some_other_field'))
        if formset.is_valid(): 
            formset.save()
            MyModel.objects.create(name=request.POST.get('name'))
            return HttpResponse("done")
```

index.html

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
        {{form}}
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

This does not work at all, cause the request.POST sends all the irrelevant data to the modelformset such as in this case, the `name` field and I end up with this error.

```
AttributeError: 'QueryDict' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

Comment: It doesn't matter that there are POST parameters that the form doesn't need. Your error is something different, can you show the full error trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how you use a `modelformset_factory`, you cannot pass the data to it. `modelformset_factory` returns a **class** which you can then instantiate to pass it the data. Did you read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets)?

So you have to first have to create the class:

```
MyModelFormset = modelformset_factory(MyModel, fields=(...), extra=...)
```

Then you instantiate it:

```
formset = MyModelFormset()
# or
formset = MyModelFormset(request.POST)
```

or you can do that at once:

```
formset = modelformset_factory(MyModel, fields=..., extra=...)(request.POST)
```